# Google Play Services for AR doesn't work for Oukitel WP22

Tags: augmented-reality

Why doesn't Google Play Services for AR, work on:
Oukitel WP15 is a clean Android 11 version?
Oukitel WP22 is a clean Android 13 version?

I hope somebody can help me, can't understand why it not supported, other phones with 11 and 13 version of Android is working.
Kind regards
Jacobsen

Download it from Google Play.